# ReactJS: Nested .map with conditional expression to match value in one array to the 2nd array

Tags: reactjs

I have two arrays (syntax is not correct but you get the picture...)
this.state.race
{
  "raceName": "President",
 "raceID": 100
}

**AND**

this.state.candidates 
{
  "canName": "John",
  "canID": 1,
  "raceID": 100
},
{
  "canName": "David",
  "canID": 2,
  "raceID": 100
},
{
  "canName": "Sally",
  "canID": 3,
  "raceID": 101
}

i want to show all the races and only the candidates that have a matching raceid

so it would be like this:

Race 100:
  1. John
  2. David

Race 101:
  {...no candidates}

my code is this:

```
render() {
  return (
    {this.state.racelist.map(myrace => (
       {myrace.title}
       <divider />
       {this.state.candidatelist.map(mycand => (
          {/********************************************************
          how can i put a conditional statment here that checks to see if,
          mycand.raceID === myrace.raceID  ???? and if those match, render
          mycand info
          ********************************************************/}
       ))}
    ))}
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using a [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) prior to doing the inner map. For example:

```
render() {
  return (
    {this.state.racelist.map(myrace => (
      {myrace.title}
      <divider />
      {this.state.candidatelist
        .filter(cand => cand.raceId === myrace.raceId)
        .map(mycand => (
          <YourComponentHere candidate={mycand}/>
        ))
      }
    ))}     
  )
}
```

This works by giving you an inner array each time that only contains the matching race id candidates. That way you only have to map.

Comment: what if that array is null?  i tried  {this.state.candidatelist && this.state.candidatelist ... .filter ...  .map   but thats not showing any of the candidates

Comment: i think the web service call with axios is taking a longer time to return the data, so how can i go about this?

Comment: Rather than doing array checks, I would use defaults instead. i.e. `const { racelist = [], condidatelist = [] } = this.state`

Comment: For async work, you should store state that contains whether or not the data has arrived. eg, set a `state.loaded = false`, and once the data arrives, set it to true. Then inside your render function, show something like loading... while the variable is false.